# Remove or Hide Add to Cart for product without stock in specific category

Tags: woocommerce, preorder

Is it possible to hide the **ADD TO CART or PREORDER button** if the backorder is enable for TEST category only if the product become out of stock.

But for other Category they can backorder or preorder the product.

```
 function test_remove_cart() {
           $product = get_product();
           if ( has_term ( 'test', 'product_cat') ) {
            global $product;
                $product->get_stock_quantity() == 0 ;

                if($product == 0){
                   remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
                   remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
                   remove_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 30 );
                   remove_action( 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 30 );
                   remove_action( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 30 );
                   remove_action( 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart', 30 );
                }
           }
        }
        add_action( 'wp', 'test_remove_cart' );
```

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ? if yes.. please show us